# pyspark performance and processing time

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, query-optimization

I have 5 steps which produced `df_a`,`df_b`,`df_c`,`df_e` and `df_f`.
Each step generates a dataframe (`df_a` for instance), and persist as parquet files.
The file is used in the sequential step (`df_b` for example).
The processing time for df_e and df_f took about 30 mins.

However, I started a new spark session, read `df_c` parquet to a data frame and processed `df_e` and `df_f`, it took less than a minute.

Was it because when we read the parquet file, it stores in a more compact way?
Should I overwrite the dataframe with the spark read after writing to storage to improve the performance?

Answer (score 1):

Using Parquet file format is definitely best from processing point of view but as you said in your case

1. Why don't u convert the very first step to parquet( start reading parquet file itself in very first step).
2. If storing intermediate df as parquet improves your performance , then may be you can apply filter to focus on the part of Data you require to read , this is as good as reading from parquet file format. because if you are storing intermediate df as parquet it is also taking some time to store the data and again reading the data into spark.